# Cannot clone repository that was clone and the account is innactive

Tags: git, github

We have a private repository that belongs to our organizition in GitHub that was forked some time ago, the account where the original repo was hosted was disabled, now new users try to clone the forked repo and it gives this error

```
git clone REPO_NAME
Cloning into bare repository 'REPO_NAME'...
ERROR: Account `SOME_GITHUB_ACCOUNT' is disabled. Please ask the owner to check their account.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

what can I do to clone this repo?

Answer (score 1):

If the original repository was private, any forks of it are considered private as well, and they are all connected to the original root repository. If the original repository is disabled, all of the forks of that repository are also disabled. The goal is that an organization can control access to forks that employees or contractors may have made. You should contact the owner, as the instructions recommend.

If you are the owner, you should reactivate or re-enable that account so that you can access it again. Then, you can ask GitHub Support to disconnect your fork from the other repository if you can show you control both accounts, and then your fork won't be affected by the disabling of the other account.

If the original repository was public and your fork was private, then the repository may have been disabled for a ToS violation or other reasons, in which case forks may be disabled as well. In this case, you could contact GitHub Support and ask them why it was disabled; it may be possible to provide evidence that your repository should be enabled or disconnected from the other forks so it can be used.

Either way, you need to contact the owner of the original account or GitHub Support. There's nothing you can do to access the account without the help of one or the other.

Comment: I already contacted GitHub so I am waiting for their answer. Thanks